# Skype plugin for Pidgin not working

Tags: gnome, skype, 14.10, pidgin

I have tried all kinds of solutions proposed here and in the wild, however, I cannot add my Skype account to Pidgin.

When I open "add new account" dialogue, I can choose between Skype and Skype-Dbus protocol alright. However, when I enter my username and click "Add", pidgin happily dies with either of them. I once got Skype asking, if I want to allow Pidgin to use public API, but since by the time the dialogue appeared Pidgin was dead, it did nothing

What have I tried:

1. Placing `libskype64.so` in `~/.purple/plugins`
2. Running `apt-get install pidgin-skype`
3. Doing `wget http://eion.robbmob.com/skype4pidgin.deb` then `sudo dpkg -i skype4pidgin.deb`
4. Placing `libskype.so` in `~/.purple/plugins`

I have checked, I have `libpurple-bin` installed, not sure if that's the `libpurple` Pidgin uses, but Facebook messaging works.

If it helps, I'm using 64bit Ubuntu 14.10 with gnome-shell DE, Skype-shell integration disabled.

EDIT: I was asked to run `pidgin` from terminal and post output. Here it is:

Yes, there is no output.

EDIT2: Running `pidgin --debug` revealed the bug; the two last lines of the output are:

```
Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Googling around I found this bug in [bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pidgin-skype/+bug/1379713). People say

> I can confirm that compiling and installing libskype64.so from source (r665) fixes the issue.

However, I do not know, how do I compile libraries.

Comment: Can't help wondering if that plugin is updated to work with Skype 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

This usually should work without any issues. We will start from the beginning. remove skype and pidgin: `sudo apt-get remove skype* pidgin*`

To get skype to work, you need `skype` itself `installed sudo apt-get install skype` and install the plugin like so: `sudo apt-get install pidgin-skype`. Select `Skype`. and i think you know the rest

[image: enter code here]

**Reference**:

- [Pidgin, the universal chat client - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/pidgin-the-universal-chat-client)

Comment: That's exactly what I meant with 2nd try. Pidgin simply shuts down after choosing Skype and pressing Add... (account)

Comment: @julka run pidgin via terminal, and post the output of that in your Question!

Comment: I did edit my question.